# How to convert session to int, when using sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using C# and have a login session.

The site will only view the news (nyhet) that the journalist have written. (It's a site where the journalist can edit the news)

```
protected void FyllNyhetDropDownList() 
{
    using (NyhetAdminDataContext dbKobling = new NyhetAdminDataContext())
    {            
        Journalist brukernavn = (from journalist in dbKobling.Journalists
                                 where journalist.JournalistId = Convert.ToInt16(Session["bruker"].ToString())
                                 select journalist).SingleOrDefault();

        List<Nyhet> nyhetliste = (from nyhet in dbKobling.Nyhets
                                  select nyhet).ToList();

        if (nyhetliste.Count() > 0)
        {
            NyhetDropDowwnList.DataTextField = "Tittel";
            NyhetDropDowwnList.DataValueField = "NyhetId";
            NyhetDropDowwnList.DataSource = nyhetliste;
            NyhetDropDowwnList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

It's here all go wrong. Can anyone help?

```
where journalist.JournalistId = Convert.ToInt16(Session["bruker"].ToString())
```

I get the error message

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The `where` clause requires a conditional statement. You're using the `=` assignment operator and not the `==` comparison operator. I would also caution you against the use of `Int16` if you need values beyond `2^16` for the `JournalistId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `==`?

```
where journalist.JournalistId == Convert.ToInt16(Session["bruker"].ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
Journalist brukernavn = dbKobling.Journalists.SingleOrDefault(x => x.JournalistId ==                                                 
                     Convert.Int16(Session["bruker"].ToString()));
```